# Dealing with mixed list of child nodes and PHP foreach

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <title>title</title>
        <link>link</link>
        <description>description</description>
        <item>
            <title>title 1</title>
            <sort>1</sort>
        </item>
        <label>
            <title>LABEL 1</title>
            <sort>2</sort>            
        </label>
        <item>
            <title>title 2</title>
            <sort>3</sort>
        </item>
        <label>
            <title>LABEL 2</title>
            <sort>4</sort>            
        </label>
        <item>
            <title>title 3</title>
            <sort>5</sort>
        </item>
        <template>3</template>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I'm using SimpleXML and I need to do a foreach on the combined list of 'item' and 'label' nodes, ignoring the rest of the 'channel' children.

I was using:

```
foreach($feed->channel->item as $item) { }
```

...and labels were added as:

```
<item type="label">
    <title>LABEL 1</title>
</item>
```

...but the consumer of the file I'm building is expecting the  node for labels.

---

**UPDATE!**

As the question didn't get posted (need a title!) and I found the answer on my own in the meantime here's what I did:

```
/* Search for items and labels */
$result = $iFeed->xpath('channel/*[name()="item" or name()="label"]');

foreach($result as $item) {
   // boom
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can also use the `|` operator.  This combines the results of multiple XPath queries.

```
$result = $root->xpath('channel/item|channel/label');
```

It looks like it also preserves the ordering of the nodes, so the nodes are returned in this order: "item, label, item, label, item" (as opposed to "item, item, item, label, label").

Comment: Confirmed. My XML is a lot more complicated than this, and sorting is being done via XSLT, but this is cleaner. Thanks!